# How to check whether the Error Page is currently shown in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress has conditional functions like `is_front_page()` or  `is_home()` to test what is currently loaded on the site.

Is there some similar function to test if the Error Page is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_404() function?
I think is this what you need.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks. But this made me think. Is 404.php only showed when 404 Error occurs?

Comment: @user850010 Actually yes! But you can configure your server to respond to custom page errors, look this: http://www.kerstner.at/en/2011/05/how-to-control-error-pages-in-wordpress/